# inbound-gateway unable to send reply

Tags: spring-integration

The below code is using Spring Integration 3.0.1

Client side integration XML:

```
    <int:channel id="serviceTWeb"></int:channel>
    <int:gateway id="serviceTGW" default-request-channel="serviceTWeb"
            service-interface="com.test.ServiceTWeb">
    </int:gateway>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
            url="http://testserver:8080/service-webapp/service"
            http-method="POST" id="RequestTNHTTP" reply-timeout="2000"
            request-channel="serviceTWeb" message-converters="conv>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <bean id="conv" class="org.springframework.integration.http.converter.SerializingHttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
```

Web side integration XML:

```
    <!-- The following uses a ServiceActivator on service -->
    <bean id="stweb" class="test.poc.si.ServiceTWeb"></bean>

    <bean id="conv" class="org.springframework.integration.http.converter.SerializingHttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="requestChannel"></int:channel>
    <int:channel id="replyChannel"></int:channel>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="requestChannel" ref="stweb"
            method="service" requires-reply="true" id="webserv"
            output-channel="replyChannel">
    </int:service-activator>
    <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
            supported-methods="POST" path="/service" message-converters="conv"
            reply-channel="replyChannel">
            </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

The client makes the request out to the server, the server side get the code
and processes the Request object, but the server tosses the following when sending the
reply message:

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Multipart] in context with path [/service-webapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Could not convert reply: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for type [com.myobject.MReply] and accept types [[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, */*;q=.2, */*;q=.2]]] with root cause
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Could not convert reply: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for type [com.myobject.MReply] and accept types [[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, */*;q=.2, */*;q=.2]

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `com.myobject.MReply` is `Serializable`, try setting `expected-response-type="com.myobject.MReply"` on the outbound gateway. It should cause the accept header to be set to `application/x-java-serialized-object`.

EDIT:

Or, set `expected-response-type="java.io.Serializable"` if you don't want to tie it to a specific type.

Comment: Is there another way to do this, I would rather not specify the expected type.

Comment: The first option worked expected-response-type="com.myobject.MReply", but when I tried the accept header in the gateway, I got the following:

Comment: The first worked, but when I tried the accept header, I got:   
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils - No property editor [com.my.ReplyEditor] found for type com.my.Reply 
according to 'Editor' suffix convention org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert 
value of type 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity' to required type 'com.my.Reply'; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] to 
required type [com.my.Reply]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found    Fix?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why that didn't work (but will look into it); it implies the `entity.hasBody()` returns false (even though the response clearly has a body). However `expected-response-type="java.io.Serializable"` works ok for me (and you don't need the accept header) because an expected response type of `Serializable` will set it.

Comment: It turns out it's the way the underlying `RestTemplate` works - if you don't give it an `expected-response-type`, you get a `ResponseEntity` with just headers and status code, no body. Sorry I misled you. So `expected-response-type` that is compatible with the response `content-type` is required; we will fix the docs. https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3452

Comment: I will make the change to use "java.io.Serializable" and post back my results.

Comment: The changes worked fine.  Another question, with the above configs how could I change from Java serialized objects to JSON?